# low cpu-usage way to monitor connection to localhost

Tags: c, linux, sockets, cpu-usage, nonblocking

It seems a nonblocking connect to localhost always fails right away then poll() returns immediately with POLLIN flag set in revents. That prevents CPU enter a blocking state and the entire system runs in quite high cpu usage.

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1470 panruoc+  20   0   12956   1956   1820 S  26.2  0.0   2:09.49 zz1
```

Here is my code of testing

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockdesc {
        char *host;
        int port;
        int sockfd;
    };
    struct sockdesc sdes[] = {
        {"localhost", 6000},
        {"111.206.239.212", 6000},
    };
    unsigned int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        tcp_connect(sdes[i].host, sdes[i].port, &sdes[i].sockfd);
        printf("sockfd = %d, %d\n", sdes[i].sockfd, errno);
    }

    if(!nonblocking)
        return 0;

    struct pollfd pollfds[2];
    pollfds[0].fd = sdes[0].sockfd;
    pollfds[1].fd = sdes[1].sockfd;
    pollfds[0].events = POLLIN;
    pollfds[1].events = POLLIN;

    int conns;
    for(conns = 0; conns != 3; ) {
        int nfds = poll(pollfds, 2, -1);
        if(nfds <= 0)
            exit(1);
        for(i = 0; (int)i < nfds; i++) {
            if(pollfds[i].revents) {
                if(pollfds[i].revents & POLLIN)
                    conns |= i;
                printf(" fd = %d, revents = 0x%04x\n", sdes[i].sockfd, pollfds[i].revents);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a low cpu-usage way to monitor for this and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop looks suspicious:

```
for(conns = 0; conns != 3; ) {
```

When does `conns` ever become three?

It seems like your intent is here:

```
            if(pollfds[i].revents & POLLIN)
                conns |= i;
```

But if `i` is `0` for the first socket, `conns |= i` will not change the value.

And when both sockets have data available, your `poll` call will start returning immediately, but you are stuck in an infinite loop.  Hence, high cpu overhead.

It appears your code's intent is to stay in a loop until both sockets have data available to read. Then break out of the loop then.  So I suspect you really meant this:

```
                conns |= (i+1);
```

There's other problems as well.  `poll` returns the number of valid socket descriptors.  Hence this line;

```
for(i = 0; (int)i < nfds; i++) {
```

So if the socket associated with pollfds[1] has data available, `nfds` will only be 1.  Hence, your loop will only evaluate if `pollfds[0]` has data.

Let's clean your code up:

```
int ready_set = 0x00;
int all_ready_set = 0x03;
int num_sockets = 2;
while (ready_set != all_ready_set)
{
    int nfds = poll(pollfds, 2, -1);

    if(nfds <= 0)
    {
        // I would not actually exit. If a socket gets closed locally, you would have a valid and expected error, but maybe that can't happen in your program
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_sockets; i++)
    {
        if (pollfds[i].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            int mask = 0x01 << i;
            pollfds[i].events = 0; // stop listening for events on this socket
            ready_set |= mask;
        }
    }
}
```